Why my git bash in vscode is so slow.and always print branch name when run command
my repo name is zoom-tool and the branch that i use is main.
when i run python script in vscode (git bash terminal) or use command like ls. It will be so slow.
and it will print >>> om-tool\x1b[36m (main)\x1b[0m\x0d\x0a$  at the end
i try using export GIT_TRACE2_PERF=1

and it seem that it trace 2 time ???
i try reinstalling git and vscode but it still slow and print the branch name. I try using gitbash outside vscode it works fine (better speed and not print om-tool\x1b[36m (main)\x1b[0m\x0d\x0a$)

This are two questions, one is why the VSCode terminal is slow when running git bash, the other is about the bash prompt set by git bash; on the first I found @CatRivas answer helpful, on the second see e.g. https://git-scm.com/book/pl/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash (look out for $PS1) (when PS1 invokes git twice, GIT_TRACE2_PERF will log twice when you hit enter in git bash)

I was having the same issue. After disabling terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled, and killing my terminal bash runs better
