Windows VS Code terminal takes about 5 seconds to return to command prompt after pressing Enter
I have tried all of the following:

Reinstalled VS Code

Cleared all roaming cache

removed all extensions

updated these settings.json
{
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "GitBash",
  "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "auto",
  "terminal.integrated.allowChords": false,
  "terminal.integrated.drawBoldTextInBrightColors": false,
  "terminal.integrated.experimentalLinkProvider": false,
  "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off",
}



Whenever I press Enter in the terminal it takes nearly 5 seconds to return to the command prompt.
I think this problem began when I had Docker running in the background and there was some lag and I hit Enter several times  to put space between my last failed test. Now it's always taking so long. I am using Git Bash as my terminal. Git Bash terminal outside of VS Code is fast.
Why is VS Code using Git Bash as the terminal suddenly really slow?

Did you try the steps give here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#:~:text=the%20steps%20below%20can%20help%20you%20investigate%20what%20might%20be%20causing%20slowness  ??

Duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78589875/why-my-git-bash-in-vscode-is-so-slow-and-always-print-branch-name-when-run-comma

@Luuk - Thanks but those steps aren't applicable here. Its not an issue of Resolving shell environment fails and its not a shell initialization slow. Its all the time now.

@Luuk it's not a duplicate of git stack trace. That is a different scenario. It might be linked but its not the cause. Marking down my question doesn't resolve the problem

Ok, I played around (for the first time using Git Bash...), and when you do export PS1="$ " it seems to work faster/better/different.

@Luuk thanks. Not sure what that does but I ran that in my terminal. I can now press Enter a bit quicker but there is still a 3 second lag before the command prompt appears

Wow, an impressive 40% gain ....   The export... caused your prompt to change (only temporarily). To do a permanent change, see: How to Shorten Git Bash Prompt (Windows)

BTW: The same info on this change of PS1 is here: https://superuser.com/a/1486994/421114  and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71355809/basic-shell-commands-extremely-slow-on-git-bash-sh-exe-but-fine-on-cygwin

@Luuk - it doesn't solve the lag for the return of the command prompt though. When I use gitbash there is not delay. When I use vscode terminal gitbash there is a delay

I'm seeing the same problem and started about the same time. Seems to be a hard fix, but may try smaller parts to see if it fixes.

Ok I solved the problem. Not sure why it went weird in the first place but this is it:

Backup vscode settings.json AND make a note of extensions installed
Uninstall vscode
Uninstall gitbash - removes C:\Program Files\Git
Delete all contents:


C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Code
C:\Users\steve.vscode
C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code


Instal GitBash - with unix options etc
Install Vscode 

Edit: settings.json
C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json



  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "GitBash": { "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "icon": "terminal-bash" }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "GitBash",
  "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "auto",
  "terminal.integrated.allowChords": false,
  "terminal.integrated.drawBoldTextInBrightColors": false,
  "terminal.integrated.experimentalLinkProvider": false,
  "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off",


install extensions
add folder to project IMPORTANT 
cd to folder

Now the terminal is super fast !!!

This issue seemed to be corrected in the latest VSCode update.
Version: 1.90.1 (user setup)
Commit: 611f9bfce64f25108829dd295f54a6894e87339d
Date: 2024-06-11T21:01:24.262Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9593362
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045


Release Notes for 1.90: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_90    Update 1.90.1:
The update addresses these issues
Which as this one: Git bash terminals have a delay after command execution #212090


interesting. Can you reference the link to this and/or release number version of vscode?

@SteveTomlin,  Release Notes for 1.90: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_90    Update 1.90.1: The update addresses these issues  which as this one in the list: Git bash terminals have a delay after command execution #212090

@david-macisso: Seeing you are new to stackoverflow, I added a comment with the requested info.  this is generally needed for future readers of your answer, to be able to verify correctness.

just saw that. Thanks. I'll add a plus to your response - thankyou, but seeing that my delay was 5s, not 1s.


Path: file name edit settings.json C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt", "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false,

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
